# Parent controller does not trigger $broadcast event for child controller on refreshing page

Tags: c#, angularjs, angular-broadcast

In Parent controller I am getting timer value in seconds and displaying it on Index page whose controller is "ParentController".

I have added one partial view using ui-view directive. Partial view's controller is "Child controller". In our case Parent controller $broadcast request to send timer value child controller.

On first attempt it works. But When you refresh page it does not broadcast timer value to child controller.

```
App.controller('**parentcontroller**', function ($scope, $http, $sce, $stateParams, $state, $modal, $timeout) {
 $http.get('/home/getTimer').
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

 $scope.$broadcast('callTimeCountdown', {timer:data});
});
}

App.controller('**childcontroller**', function ($scope, $http, $sce, $stateParams, $state, $modal, $timeout) {


$scope.$on('callTimeCountdown', function (event, args) {

alert("In child controller");
            });
}
```

Comment: what do you mean it works on first attempt ?

Comment: when we route normally to index page (whose controller is parent controller) on first it works . But if  we refresh page it doesnt call to child controller event which is second case.  As we observed after refresh when $broadcast triggers by that time childcontroller was not loaded.

Comment: you should probably add some html and a plunkr would be good. How is childcontroller initiated? Are you using angular-router or ui-router ?

Comment: I am using ui-router